# Development() takes no arguments?

Tags: python

```
class Club:
    keyword = ""
    def introduce(cls):
        print('[%s Club]'%cls.keyword)
    def printInfo(self):
        print("Hello we are %s ."%self.name)
        print("leader:",self.manager)
        print("leader tel number",self.tel)

class Development(Club):

    def special(self,notice):
        print(self.notice)


name=input()
manager=input()
tel=input()
notice=input()

development= Development(name,manager,tel,notice)
development.introduce()
development.printInfo()
development.sepcial()
```

so I keep getting an error saying for "development= Development(name,manager,tel,notice)" saying that Development() takes no arguments I tried changing the method and everything but it didn't work. Also is this how you do class inheritance? because I am not quite sure if this is how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

you need a constructor or `__init__()` method for you class. Without specifying an explicit constructor, interpreter has no way of knowing how many parameters your class is supposed to take. You need to add something like this:

```
class Development(Club):
    def __init__(name, manager, tel, notice):
        self.name = name
        self.manager = manager
        self.tel = tel
        self.notice = notice

    def special(self,notice):
        print(self.notice)
```